# C/Postgres - Using palloc in a non-PG function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm currently implementing a user-defined data type - a linked list that mimics a set of integers in a file called intList.c, and hopefully used with intList.source to install it onto my Postgres server.

So my questions are the following:

1. Can I write C functions such as (link newNode) and (link InsertEnd) in my code wherein they're not postgres functions to be declared & created in the source file?
2. Can I use `palloc` in a function called from my input function? (in this case link newNode)? Or should I do it in my input function?

My code for intList.c is as follows: P.S. These functions all work in C, but I haven't installed them in my PostgreSQL server so I don't know how it'll turn out:

```
 // Defining struct for linked list
 typedef struct intSet *link;

 typedef struct intList {
    int num;
    link next;
 } intList;

 //  Create a new node
 link newNode(int item) {
     link n = (link) palloc(sizeof(*n));
     n->num = item;
     n->next = NULL;
     return n;
 }

 link insertEnd(link list, link n){
     link curr;
     // Empty list
     if(list == NULL){
         list = n;
         n->next = NULL;
     // If list not empty, iterate to end of list, then append
     } else {
         for(curr = list; curr->next != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
         }
         curr->next = n;
         n->next = NULL;
     }
     return list;
 }    

 PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(intList_in);

 Datum
 intList_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
 {
     char       *str = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
     char       *token;

     // Create an empty linked list
     link newList;
     newList = NULL;

     // Get individual ints from a set e.g. {1, 2, 3, 4}
     token = strtok(str, ",{} ");

     // For each int, create a new node then
     // append to list
     while (token != NULL) {
         link a = NULL;
         a = newNode(atoi(token));
         newList = insertEnd(newList, a);
         token = strtok(NULL, ",{} ");
     }

     PG_RETURN_POINTER(newList);
 }

 Datum
 intList_out(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
 {
     // Start our string
     char* out = "{";
     char* num;
     // Retrieve our list from arg(0)
     link List = PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
     link curr;
     // Traverse list till last node, add commas after each node
     for (curr = List; curr->next != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
         num = itoa(curr->num);
         strcat(num, ", "); 
         strcat(out, num);
     }
     // At last node, add closing bracket to close list
     num = itoa(curr->num);
     strcat(num, "}");
     strcat(out, num);

     // Psprintf to result then return it
     char *result;
     result = psprintf("%s", out);
     PG_RETURN_CSTRING(result);

 }
```

This is only a part of my entire code, I'll be implementing operators and other functions so any tips and pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) `token = strtok(str, ",{} ");` strtok() willdamage the str (which couldbe read-only,or partof a buffer or struct) 2) `num = itoa(curr->num);
         strcat(num, ", "); 
         strcat(out, num);` will certainly segfault.

Comment: In the case of 1), I could make another string with strcpy, but what could you recommend I do in place of 2)? The only thing I could think of was defining the size of "out" to be BUFSIZ or something large.

Comment: I would not use strtok() at all:  there is also a  0) `strtok()` relies on static data, using your code in multiple places within the same query (not impossible) could cause strange results, at least.

Comment: Well in that case stcpy will do the job and thanks for pointing out the segfault, itoa was certainly not a standard function so sprintf did the job, then I just used a static string that'll be reset for each call.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I write C functions such as (link newNode) and (link InsertEnd) in my code wherein they're not postgres functions to be declared & created in the source file?

I assume you mean can you write them without `palloc`. Sure, you can. Though it's not advised. PostgreSQL wraps `malloc` for **both** performance reasons and for integrity reasons (making sure memory is freed at the end of txn). You'll have to take care of that without `palloc`, and I'm not sure what kind of challenges you'll encounter.

> Can I use `palloc` in a function called from my input function? (in this case link newNode)? Or should I do it in my input function?

Sure, if you're running on the server That's what you're supposed to do. Just `#include <postres.h>`